# How do I dynamically load device tree overlays using overlayfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I'm having some trouble enabling overlayfs on my board (ROCKPRO64).  It's running vanilla mainline Linux 5.9.
I have configfs and overlayfs enabled, but the device-tree directory doesn't populate in /sys/kernel/config.
My understanding is that the automatic mounting of this device-tree directory in configfs is provided by a custom patch found in board specific kernels.
In terms of mounting, I am pretty confused by the documentation in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation...rlayfs.txt.
How can I manually mount this overlayfs device-tree directory to configfs to be able to dynamically load DTOs?

Comment: overlayfs is nothing to do with device tree overlays.

Comment: Vanilla kernel does not support loading device tree overlays via configfs, but there are patches to support it. See [topic/overlays](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/geert/renesas-drivers.git/log/?h=topic/overlays).

Comment: @IanAbbott ah, I see.  Perhaps I was confused by the requirement of `CONFIG_OF_OVERLAY` for dynamic DTO.  I think I get it a bit better now.
So since dynamic DTO loading is not available in userspace on mailine, one needs to write a kernel module (one per DTO?) taking advantage of the functions defined in drivers/of/overlay.c // of_private.h-- and this link you sent is just an extension of that idea, utilizing configfs to make loading readily available via userspace?

Comment: Yes, the DT-Overlay configfs interface provided by the extension is included in the Raspberry Pi kernels, for example (or at least a modified, earlier version of it).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with a vanilla kernel.

CONFIG_OF_OVERLAY enables dynamic DT overlays, but doesn't provide the configfs interface. The author (Pantelis Antoniou) has, however, submitted the patch required (CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS): https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1395179766-31575-4-git-send-email-pantelis.antoniou@konsulko.com/

See also:
[https://elinux.org/Frank's_Evolving_Overlay_Thoughts](https://elinux.org/Frank%27s_Evolving_Overlay_Thoughts)